# Is it safe to delete the .gem directory for a RubyGem I installed in the wrong place?

Tags: installation, rubygems

I wanted to install open4 so I typed

```
gem install open4
```

which gave me the following warnings:

```
WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /var/lib/gems/1.8 and   
          /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin aren't both writable.  
WARNING:  You don't have /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,  
          gem executables will not run.
```

I then did

```
sudo install open4
```

and it appears to have installed.

How could I go about removing the extra installation from my home directory? Would just deleting the ~/.gem directory be appropriate or would that be harmful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out (without manually deleting the directories.) Typing
  ruby env
and looking under "GEM PATHS" :
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8
The second line referring to the erroneous installation.

I then did
gem uninstall open4 -i /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8
and got
Successfully uninstalled open4-1.0.1

Hooray.